# how to use php variable value in jquery for future scope

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have four colors which are used according to requested URL.
These four colors, i need to use and show in background of selected day of calendar.
as showing in calendar.
I have tried but not getting success.

I am coming from prev page with selected option and on click url generated

CSS for selected day

```
.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**standard j query for calendar**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: ''/*,next,today'*/,
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next'/*'month,basicWeek,basicDay'*/
        },
        editable: true,
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            var myDate = new Date();
            if (date < myDate) { 
                // Do not do anything
            } else {
                console.info($.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'));
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.click_selected').removeClass('click_selected');
                // change the day's background color just for fun
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('click_selected'); 
                $("#selectedDate").val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'));
            }     
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your php seems just fine. What's the value of `$bookingTtype` when you load the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `$(".click_selected").css({'background-color':'<?php echo $key;?>'});` 
you are assigning bg color to all elements currently having click_selected class

But what you actually need is to set another bg color for the click_selected class.

You can do something like this in your head section:

```
<style>
    .click_selected { 
        background-color:<?php echo $key;?>;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can assign php values to javascript variables like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jVariable ="<?php echo $phpValue;?>";
});
```

Then you can use `jVariable` inside your javascript.

in your script you can write all code inside

```
$(document).ready(function{
   <?php
        $bookingTtype = strtolower(base64_decode($get['opt']));     
        $colorArray = array("#D3542D"=>"meeting_room","#509DCE"=>"conference_room","#F3B804"=>"hot_desk","#7AB44C"=>"solo_studio"); 
        $key = array_search($bookingTtype , $colorArray);
    ?>
    $(".click_selected").css({'background-color':'<?php echo $key;?>'});
});
```